# Command not called, anything wrong with this spawn syntax?

Tags: node.js

When i run this pidof command by hand, it works. Then put into my server.js.

```
// send signal to start the install script
var spw = cp.spawn('/sbin/pidof', ['-x', 'wait4signal.py', '|', 'xargs', 'kill', '-USR1']);

spw.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write('----- Install Error !!! -----\n');
    res.write(data.toString());
    console.log(data.toString());
});

spw.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write('----- Install Data -----\n');
    res.write(data.toString());
    console.log(data.toString());
});

spw.on('close', function(data) {
    res.end('----- Install Finished, please to to status page !!! -----\n');
    console.log('88');
});
```

In the web i only see "----- Install Finished, please to to status page !!!". My install script seems never get this USR1 signal. Anything wrong please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two separate commands. You are piping the output of your `/sbin/pidof` command to the input stream of your `xargs` command. If you are using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) (rather than [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), which a string exactly as you would write on the command line), you need to spawn one process per command.

Spawn your processes like this:

```
const pidof = spawn('/sbin/pidof', ['-x', 'wait4signal.py']);
const xargs = spawn('xargs', ['kill', '-USR1']);
```

Now pipe the output of the first process to the input of the second, like so:

```
pidof.stdout.pipe(xargs.stdin);
```

Now you can listen to events on your `xargs` process, like so:

```
xargs.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Good point, maybe i should just use exec() instead. Will give it a try tomorrow, thanks !

Comment: `spawn()` is more flexible. It looks like it's probably right for what you want to do.